# Angular Universal: How to create an app shell and only pre-render the shell?

Tags: angular, typescript, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

**Background**

In order to speed up the perceived performance of my angular 7 app, I am trying to add an app shell to my application, and pre-render that shell using angular universal. To do so, I am following these [steps](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-app-shell).

**Problem**

When I execute the command from Step 3 from the above link (`ng run my-app:app-shell`), the process fails because it appears that angular universal is trying to build my entire app using the node environment, and there are portions of my app that are not compatible with angular universal. I don't need the entire app to be rendered or be compatible with angular universal, only the app shell component.

**Questions**

1. How do I only include the app shell to be pre-rendered during the `ng run my-app:app-shell` command?
2. Also, that command builds the rest of the app in development mode. How do I trigger a prod build instead?

Comment: you can trigger the production build by using ng run my-app:app-shell:production and add production builds to your configuration i.e my-app:build:production

I think I have a similar issue to you as I get ReferenceError: window is not defined when I build my app-shell

Comment: The `ng run my-app:app-shell` command runs two builds under the surface: `my-app:build:production` and `my-app:server:production`. The issue is that when it tries to build the server portion with ng-universal, that's when it's throwing the errors. That's because it's building components during the server build that I don't need it to actually pre-render ever.  I only want to pre-render the app shell. As in, the only thing I want to get built during the server build is the app-shell. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: "SSR can work together with an AppShell, if you're using Service Workers. The idea is that the first ever load is SSR'd, the SW is installed, and then the SW is instructed to cache the App Shell, so future loads take place entirely on the client using the shell. But if you are not using Service workers, there's no point in doing SSR together with an App Shell as full server-side rendering is strictly better." https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12310#issuecomment-437604135

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question. I found the answer here:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11478#issuecomment-423825620

```
ng run my-app:app-shell -c production
```